# "There is still no" vs 'There is still not a...'

Tags: there-is

Is there a difference between the following?

```
 1. There is still no good method...
 2. There is still not a good method...
```

Also, what is the correct usage of articles here (in singular).

Kind regards,
Dmtiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 
They both are the same thing.